# pandas merge dataframes on certain columns but exclude them in the result dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

In `pandas`, I have to include certain columns that I want to merge two `dataframe`s on,

```
result = df_a.merge(df_b[['A', 'B', 'C']], how='left', on=['A', 'B'])
```

so if I want to merge `df_a` and `df_b` on columns `A` and `B`, I have to also include `A` and `B` in the `result` `dataframe`, but what I really want is only column `C`. I am wondering if there a way to only include `C` in `merge`.

A sample result dataframe after merge,

```
year_x    code_x    year_y    code_y    id
2000      005       2000.00   005       1
2001      006       2001.00   006       2
2002      007       2002.00   007       3
```

`df_a` and `df_b` all contain `year` and `code`, I only need `id` from `df_b`, but I have to `merge` on `code` and `year`.

originally `year` is of `int64` dtype in both `df_a` and `df_b`, but after the merge `year_y` turned into `float`, which is also confusing.

If I `drop` `code_y` and `year_y` after the `merge`, I may have to `rename` `code_x` and `year_x` back to `code` and `year`, which is not convenient if I can eliminate the duplicate columns in the first place.

Comment: why not `drop` it  after merge

Comment: @Wen was wondering if it can be done in `merge` along without some clean up after the merge.

Comment: Can you add sample dataframe

Comment: There were many questions like this before and dropping after merge or quering is usually used. If you add the sample data we can think of better alternative

Comment: @Bharathshetty a sample has been added in the op.

Comment: Would this be of any help  ? `df1[['code','year','id']].merge(df2[['code','year']])['id']`

Comment: @Bharathshetty got KeyError: 'id'

Comment: Which dataframe has Id column in ur dataframes?

Comment: @Bharathshetty `df_b` has `id`

Comment: Then `df2[['code','year','id']].merge(df1[['code','year']])['id']` would do I think

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the one column in the result frame:

```
result = df_a.merge(df_b[['A', 'B', 'C']], how='left', on=['A', 'B'])['C']
```

As for your changing `dtypes`, it looks, at least in the sample data you provided, that your `year_x` and `year_y` are different types, one being `int` and one being `float`, which means the resulting column will be `float`.